# np.where doesnt work with specific colors

Tags: python, numpy

[image: template image]

im trying to make the template image black except for the red rectangle which has BGR [0, 4, 95]. below code works for other colored rectangles but i figured it wont work sometimes with specific BGR. (in this case, it wont work with [0, 4, 95]) i have no idea why it wont.
can anyone tell me what im missing?

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

output_color = [0,4,95]

img = cv2.imread('1.png', cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGRA2BGR)


img = np.where(np.all(img == output_color, axis=2, keepdims=True), output_color, [0, 0, 0])
img = img[..., 0].astype('uint8')

cv2.imshow("output", img)
cv2.waitKey()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

result i get

[image]

result i want

[image: result i want]

Comment: My chrome color picker says it's `88,5,0` (RGB)

Comment: Try cv2.inRange instead. Sometimes the image compression shift the color value ever so slightly